# Changing the content of a matrix in a structure in C

Tags: c, pointers, matrix

I am currently working on an assignment for school and currently I am stuck. What I am trying to achieve is, in my opinion, rather simple. I have defined a structure. In this structure I made a matrix. The next thing I want to do is to add information to this matrix by only using a pointer to that structure.

So here is my structure:

```
typedef struct maze{
    char mazeMatrix[6][10];
};
```

and my pointer to that structure:

```
typedef struct maze* mazePointer;
```

I then initialize this within another function. I have been looking for the required syntax on numerous of websites but I cant find the required syntax. How can I change the content of the matrix, so for instance I want to change the first entry (first row, first column) `mazeMatrix[0][0]` with "H". What would be the syntax for achieving this?

I am also giving the pointer to a function that needs to update the structure.

Comment: You really should show the context of what you've tried and the errors reported by the compiler.  This is, as you think, very simple (at least, once you've done it a few times).  But your compiler warnings would help...or, if the code compiled, maybe the trouble was that you were passing the structure by value, not by reference, so the function was modifying a copy of the maze and not the maze itself.  We can't tell because you didn't show us an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
mazePointer mp = ...;

mp->mazeMatrix[0][0] = 'H';
```

Personally, I'd rather not hide pointers in the typedef, so I'd use:

```
typedef struct Maze { char mazeMatrix[6][10]; } Maze;

Maze *mp = ...;
mp->mazeMatrix[0][0] = 'H';
```

The end line is the same.  Note that your `typedef struct maze { ...};` doesn't define a name for the type; the keyword `typedef` is superfluous and should be removed (and good compilers will warn you about that).  I would probably also simply use the word `matrix` rather than `mazeMatrix`; it the structure is a maze, the matrix inside it is the maze's matrix, without the need for the prefix.

---

Calling context:

```
Maze m;

maze_modifier(&m);
```

Called context:

```
void maze_modifier(Maze *mp)
{
    mp->mazeMatrix[0][0] = 'H';
    ...
}
```

---

> My next issue is then printing this matrix from a pointer. I am using:
>
> ```
> printf("%c", mazePointer->matrix[counter][counterA]);
> ```
>
> The counters are just 2 variables from 2 nested for loops. Any suggestions?

That should work.  So should this:

```
void maze_printer(Maze *mp)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            putchar(mp->mazeMatrix[i][j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```